# Python - My CTkRadioButtons accept more than one selection

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, radio-button, customtkinter

I have a problem with the three radio buttons, which is that they accept all of them to be selected at once. How do I prevent this thing, and when I press the other button, the selection goes back from that first one?

```
    pen_size_1 = customtkinter.CTkRadioButton(pen_size_frame, 
                                        text="Small", 
                                        value=3, 
                                        command=lambda: change_size(3),
                                        state="normal",
                                        fg_color="#ad85b9",
                                        hover_color= "#a655be",
                                        )
pen_size_1.pack(side="left")


pen_size_2 = customtkinter.CTkRadioButton(pen_size_frame, 
                                        text="Medium", 
                                        value=5, 
                                        command=lambda: change_size(5), 
                                        fg_color="#ad85b9",
                                        hover_color= "#a655be",
                                        
                                        )
pen_size_2.pack(side="left")

pen_size_3 = customtkinter.CTkRadioButton(pen_size_frame, 
                                        text="Large", 
                                        value=7, 
                                        command=lambda: change_size(7), 
                                        state="normal",
                                        fg_color="#ad85b9",
                                        hover_color= "#a655be"
                                        )
pen_size_3.pack(side="left")
```

Comment: You need to assign the `variable` option of these buttons to same tkinter variable.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments by [acw1668](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5317403/acw1668) you have to introduce one `IntVar` for all the radiobuttons to store the value of the selected one. Further you can reduce the number of redundant lines of code by generating the radiobuttons from a loop:

```py
pen_size_var = tkinter.IntVar(value=3)  # set start value here

pen_size_rbtn = []
for i, size in enumerate(['Small', 'Medium', 'Large'], 1):
    pen_size_rbtn.append(customtkinter.CTkRadioButton(pen_size_frame,
                                                      text=size,
                                                      value=i*2+1,
                                                      variable=pen_size_var,
                                                      state="normal",
                                                      fg_color="#ad85b9",
                                                      hover_color="#a655be",))
    pen_size_rbtn[-1].pack(side="left")
```

Whatever variable is set by your `change_size()` function can now be replaced by `pen_size_var`

Comment: Note that first argument of `IntVar()` is the master of the variable, not the value.  Use `value=3` instead. Please test your solution before posting.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I edited my post accordingly. Must have slipped my attention.